# How to get the page title in a Liferay velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity

How can I get the title of current page in a CMS velocity template ?

I need the same String as is shown in the last part of the breadcrump, in other words, the page title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out how to do it. 
It's necessary to access through the $themeDisplay

```
##Take layout id
#set ($layoutId = $request.get("theme-display").get("plid"))

## get the service for layout
#set($layoutService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService"))

##convert the layout id into long
#set ($layoutLong = $getterUtil.getLong($layoutId))

##take a layout object
#set($layout = $layoutService.getLayout($layoutLong))
#set ($pageName = $layout.getName($locale))
```

That's it.

Comment: Include the reference: https://sushilsaini.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/liferay-embed-the-page-title-in-layout-template/

Answer (score 1):

In a theme template: `$page.getHTMLTitle($locale)`

From a CMS template I'll have to dig a bit deeper for the answer... let me know if the theme is sufficient

Comment: Thanks anyway, but what I need is just in an CMS template.

Answer (score 1):

In addition with larrytron code, It's usefull to declare this line in portal-ext.properties to use restricted variables in CMS Template

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```